# How to add animtion in Horizonal Pager in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have a HorizonalPager but there is no animation means it goes to second page suddenly i want that it animates to go softly or little bit slow and How to get rid of those stretch animation or whatever they are called

Here is a gif

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue when I used old version of library:

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.20.0"
```

But when I updated it to

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.23.0"
```

all went good. Try it.

Comment: Thanks it worked but what about that stretch animation?

Comment: In my case stretch animation was fixed once I update the library